# AWS Cloudsearch removes empty strings from arrays

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

If I upload a document with the following field value:

```
  "my_array": ["one", "", "three", "four"],
```

then this gets returned from the search api:

```
  "my_array": ["one", "three", "four"],
```

i.e. the blank string is removed. This happens for both `literal-array` and  `text-array` fields.

Is there any way to configure Cloudsearch to not do this?

It seems surprising that Cloudsearch would "silently" mutate the data I upload to it. I haven't managed to find anything relevant in the documentation.